# Arduino Mega 2560 and servo motor in Proteus

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

Can I get help to connect Arduino Mega 2560 and servo motor in Proteus 7.8
correctly because I tried this connection, in the image below, with `sweep.ino.hex` in the Arduino software examples but did not work!

[image: Connection between Arduino Mega 2560 and servo motor]

Comment: What didn't work exactly?

Comment: servo motor didn't work exactly !